# Replace word by word in a string

Tags: python, replace

I want to replace a word in a string which is determined by the word entered by the user.

For example, if user enters `"pot"`, the code replaces it with `"who"` but if he enters `"top"` then it becomes `"mam"`.

I have a set of 225 words and their replacements. I am using python for this. Replacing each word individually in a condition is really impractical. is their a quicker way to do this. I currently have no code as I am totally confused how to do this.

Using excel throws an error no matter what.

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: How are you words and replacements stored ? Is it a dictionary ?

Comment: What makes this impractical?  How are you currently doing it?

Comment: Even If I use a dictionary, 225 words are a lot.

Comment: @ScottHunter I am trying using excel file but it throws an error

Comment: 225 is 225. If you have that many pairs then you need a dictionary of that size. If the word list is stored in a file then you can write code to read that file and populated a dictionary.

Comment: so if I use 2 lists, how will I convert them to a dict

Comment: `d = dict(zip(list1,list2))` will construct a dictionary from two lists.

Comment: I hope it opens and @JohnColeman thankyou for helping. Then post this as an answer and I will mark your as the best

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a very convenient way to do this; python `dict`s:

```
d = {"pot": "who", "top": "mam"}
print(d["pot"])
print(d["top"])
```

Output:

```
who
mam
```

In Python 3.1, you can use the new `match` - `case` statement:

```
s = "pot"

match s: 
   case "pot": 
       print("who")
   case "top": 
       print("top")
    case _: 
       print(None)
```